Does temperature difference alone equate to stored energy?
A heat engine uses a temperature difference in a hot side and a cold side to produce work. But when you run a heat engine, with a fixed amount of heat in the hot and cold sides until equilibrium is reached, would their combined thermal temperature be less than if you placed them side by side, and let the heat flow directly? I know a hot object and a cold object with a given amount of thermal energy has less entropy than a medium-hot object with the same total thermal energy, but does the temperature difference alone account for any sort of 'stored' energy?
Similar to if you have uneven glasses of water compared to even ones, even if the total water is the same, the uneven ones have more gravitational potential energy. My question is does the water analogy apply to heat, where uneven distributions of heat alone account for any form of stored 'heat potential energy,' regardless the thermal energy of the heat alone?
Although separating a medium-temperature body into a hot side and a cold side requires reversing entropy, does doing so require any work, entropy aside?
If the answer is yes, if you let a temperature difference equalize without extracting the energy via a heat engine, where does the 'heat potential energy' go?

If you use the engine to extract work, part of the energy stored in the heat reservoirs is taken somewhere else outside the system (for instance, you can store the work done as mechanical energy). If you let the two heat sources to reach thermal equilibrium without the engine making any work, then the final temperature will be larger, simply because there will more internal energy in the reservoirs.
In general, the temperature difference between two sources is telling you how much amount of heat (disordered energy) you can transform into useful work (ordered energy). Another way to see it, a large temperature difference has less entropy and its energy can be manipulated to extract some work. Uniform temperature means large entropy and no capacity to transform random heat energy into work.
